# Saving a extended user profile

Tags: django, django-models

I need save additional information about users when they register.
I used this: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users
, but I stuck. Relation are created, but the field `key` is empty.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True)
    key = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.user

def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

views.py

```
def registration(request):
    form = RegistrationForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
        last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        user = User.objects.create_user(login, email, password)
        user.first_name = first_name
        user.last_name = last_name
        user.is_active = False
        # I've tried both ways, but it not write anything in to the table
        # user.key = ''.join(random.choice(string.digits) for i in range(12))
        # user.get_profile().key = ''.join(random.choice(string.digits) for i in range(12))

        user.save()
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
profile = user.get_profile()
profile.key = ''.join(random.choice(string.digits) for i in range(12))
profile.save()
user.save()
```

This is the correct way to do it. You have to save the instance of the profile object as well as the user object

Comment: None of the custom user profile tutorials seem to mention this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this,

`@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_or_update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
    instance.profile.save()`

Comment: Hey, can you tell me please why have you written `instance.profile.save()`? why do we need it? isn't it enough to create profile only when it's created ?